# VINCULAR(MESCALR) VALORES NO DATAFRAME "PANDAS"

Tags: pandas, concatenação-de-string, merge

Olá,
estou criando uma tabela que atualiza a cada 30min, e a cada atualização sempre vem um valor diferente em uma coluna especifica, só que ao utilizar o merge, cria-se outra coluna nos locais em que possuem informações anteriores:

df1 =

```
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| PLACA    | ID     | NOME             | FUNC      | INFO2    |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| MKB0000  | 012345 | FULAN DE TAL     | PROFESSOR | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| RLS2135  | 784512 | CICRANO          | PROFESSOR | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| ABC1234  | 895623 | BOLO DE POTE     | VENDEDOR  | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| XYZ0000  | 124578 | VINGART LEVIOSEN | VENDEDOR  | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| POK1234  | 235689 | TORHOFIN         | PROFESSOR | INICIOU  |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| OLA123   | 744815 | TIGRESA VIP      | PROFESSOR | PAUSA    |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| NMN1212  | 326159 | BLUE PEN         | VENDEDOR  | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| HIH12312 | 794613 | MC PIPOKINHA     | PROFESSOR | TERMINOU |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| COM123   | 001258 | REI DE ROMA      | VENDEDOR  | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+
```

df2 =

```
+--------+----------+
| ID     | INFO2    |
+--------+----------+
| 012345 | INICIOU  |
+--------+----------+
| 235689 | TERMINOU |
+--------+----------+
| 744815 | TERMINOU |
+--------+----------+


import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv('list.csv', sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('list2.csv', sep=';')

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how='left')





result

+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| PLACA    | ID     | NOME             | FUNC      | INFO2_x  | INFO2_y  |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| MKB0000  | 012345 | FULAN DE TAL     | PROFESSOR | NaN      | INICIOU  |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| RLS2135  | 784512 | CICRANO          | PROFESSOR | NaN      | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| ABC1234  | 895623 | BOLO DE POTE     | VENDEDOR  | NaN      | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| XYZ0000  | 124578 | VINGART LEVIOSEN | VENDEDOR  | NaN      | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| POK1234  | 235689 | TORHOFIN         | PROFESSOR | INICIOU  | TERMINOU |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| OLA123   | 744815 | TIGRESA VIP      | PROFESSOR | PAUSA    | TERMINOU |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| NMN1212  | 326159 | BLUE PEN         | VENDEDOR  | NaN      | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| HIH12312 | 794613 | MC PIPOKINHA     | PROFESSOR | TERMINOU | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| COM123   | 001258 | REI DE ROMA      | VENDEDOR  | NaN      | NaN      |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Já tentei o modo CONCAT e outras formas de mesclagem.

Resumindo, há alguma forma de não criar essa segunda coluna, e substituir os valores atuais da coluna INFO2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use o campo **ID** como index em ambos os DataFrames usando `.set_index()` e atualize os campos necessários com `update()`.

```
df1 = df1.set_index("ID")
df2 = df2.set_index("ID")

df1.update(df2)
```